# Suspended from reviews even though editors could have improved the question

Tags: discussion, triage, review-suspension

I got the following message when reviewing:

> Your review on triage/25151211 wasn't helpful. "Requires Editing" should only be used when other community users (like you) are able to edit/format the question into a better shape. If a question is unsalvagable and/or can only be improved by the author, please flag/vote to close or delete instead. For more information, see meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389148.
>
> Come back in 15 hours to continue reviewing.

Here is the link to the review in question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25151211

However, in this case I disagree with the review suspension, and two other reviewers seem to agree with me, because in total three of us decided on `Requires Editing`, and only one person decided to choose `Unsalvageable`.

Also, I do think that people other than the OP could have improved this question significantly, for example by:

- improving grammar/sentence formatting
- removing the `enter code here`
- copying code from the `codepen` link into the question

It was later decided that the question was not focused enough. However, I still don't think that the message:

> "Requires Editing" should only be used when other community users (like you) are able to edit/format the question into a better shape.

is applicable to this case, because anyone *could have improved* the question.

I think that review suspensions should only be used when the review was **incorrect**, for example if someone chooses `Requires Editing` even though the OP would have to provide more information, but not when one other person decides later on that another review might have been more appropriate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> copying code from the codepen link into the question

No, the community can't do that, because **we can't verify who the author is**. We wouldn't want the community to violate copyright restrictions here.

The post is only salvageable by the author, not the community, so *Requires editing* is not the correct choice here.

> [T]wo other reviewers seem to agree with me, because in total three of us decided on *Requires Editing*, and only one person decided to choose *Unsalvageable*.

Just because others have made the same mistake, doesn't mean your mistake was okay to make. The other *Requires Editing* reviewers also received a review suspension here. The goal of the suspension is *to get your attention* and verify your reviews. Since we managed to do so, I've lifted your suspension.

Comment: I still believe that the review suspension was unhelpful in this case. This was my mistake in reality, not what the suspension explained to me. If you hadn't answered, or I hadn't created this post, I still would be none the wiser. On the other hand, I do also understand that there is not always enough time for a personalised message.

Comment: @Run_Script see also [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code)

Comment: @Run_script unhelpful? The suspension made you post this, got you the answer you needed, and educated you to do better reviews. I would say the suspension did exactly what it was mean to do

Answer (score 2):

Your review was incorrect, but not for the reasons you stated.

The question did not contain code, only a link to the code. If a user had made the edits you suggested, the question would still be a candidate for closure as the code was not shown in the question. Using links for code makes them vulnerable to link rot and make it harder to readers to reproduce the problem.

The suspension is to alert you to look closer.

Comment: For the same reason you gave (link rot), I though that it would be a good idea for someone to copy the code from the `codepen` link straight into the question, so that it is always there even when the link changes. Any editor could have done this.